# Execution order in Rx.NET, ReactiveUI

Tags: reactive-programming, system.reactive, reactiveui, rx.net

What will be the good solution in Rx.NET and/or ReactiveUI for this case:
There is single MainDateTimeRange object and its StartDateTime and EndDateTime are observed by a number of objects-subscribers. When the period changes then the subscribers should refresh their data collection.

But the order of refereshing is important.
First should be refereshed priority object-subscriber and after the others.

Priority object is the one which is currently shown in GUI and other are refreshed later in background.

Comment: Please show the classes and observables involved. i.e. You have `IObservable<X>` and `X` is `public class X { }` and you have `IObservable<Y>`, etc. From your description I think I see `IObservable<DateRange>` and `IObservable<GuiObject>`, but I don't want to guess these things.

Comment: There is no priority queue based system at the moment in Rx. My solution in the past for these types of issues is to have a PriorityQueue in a manager class, the PriorityQueue having the priority value and a Subject<T> then each time you get new values you can just trigger all the subjects. The other way you could do it is use one of the operators in the Rx code base and create your own "sink"